# PHP srv_query Not Returning Results from some Stored Procedures

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, migration

I am migrating a site from PHP 5.6.40 to PHP 7.2.15 and some of the stored procedures (SP) are returning empty statements. Some SP run fine other do not. The SP run fine from Management Studio.

```
    protected function __query() {

      $args = func_get_args();
      $query = array_shift($args);

      foreach($args as &$arg) {
          $arg = $this->__ms_sql_escape($arg);
      }

      $query = vsprintf($query, $args);
      $res1 = sqlsrv_query($this->_db, $query );

      if(true) {  // make it easy to switch in and out debugging
        echo "<br>jjnj-dba-10<br>";
        echo "Query: " . $query . "<br>";
        echo "jjnj-dba-20 dump follows: <br>";
        var_dump($res1);
        echo "<br>jjnj-dba-30 post dump: <br>";
        print_r(sqlsrv_errors());
        echo "<br>jjnj-dba-40 post errors: <br>";
      }

      return $this->__toArray($res1);
    }  // End query


    protected function __toArray($resultIn) {

      if($resultIn) {
        $results = array();
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultIn, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $results[] = $row;
        }
        sqlsrv_free_stmt ( $resultIn );
        return $results;
      } else {
        return(false);
      }
    }  // End to array
```

Calling the SP

```
    class RisingStars extends DbAdaptor {  // DbAdaptor contains the above functions
    ....
    function getFeaturedRisingStar() {
      $data = $this->__query('exec getRisingStarFeatured ' );
      var_dump($data);
      return $data[0];
    }
```

The SP

```
USE [dbName]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getRisingStarFeatured]

AS
 SET NOCOUNT ON

 SELECT  --  [getRisingStarFeatured]
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ra.race_date, 1) AS race_date    
      ,ra.track_id
      ...
      ,cu.name as currency_name
 FROM ( SELECT
       q2.id
      ...
      ,q2.created_by
      FROM (
        (SELECT  q1.id
              ,q1.race_id
              ...
              ,q1.created_by
        FROM
        (SELECT r.id
              ,r.race_id
              ...
              ,r.created_by
          FROM dbo.rising_star r
          LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.horse h on r.horse_id = h.id
          WHERE horse_id = (SELECT rs.horse_id from rising_star rs where id =  (SELECT MAX(id) from rising_star )
                           )
           )  q1

  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.horse h1 on q1.dam_id = h1.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.horse h1a on q1.sire_id = h1a.id)    q2 

  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.horse h2 on q2.dam_dam_id = h2.id )) q3
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.horse h3 on q3.dam_dam_dam_id = h3.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.horse h4 ON q3.dam_sire_id = h4.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.horse h5 on q3.dam_dam_sire_id = h5.id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.horse h6 on h3.sire_id = h6.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.files f on q3.pedigree_file_id = f.id
  JOIN dbo.race ra on q3.race_id = ra.id
  JOIN dbo.track t on ra.track_id = t.id
  JOIN dbo.country c on t.country_id = c.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.currency cu on c.currency_id = cu.id
  JOIN dbo.race_type rt ON ra.type_id = rt.id
  JOIN dbo.horse_gender g on q3.gender_id = g.id
  ORDER BY ra.race_date DESC
```

The output:

```
jjnj-dba-10
Query: exec getRisingStarFeatured 
jjnj-dba-20 dump follows: 
resource(736) of type (SQL Server Statement) 
jjnj-dba-30 post dump: 

jjnj-dba-40 post errors: 
jjnj-dba-300 in to array 
array(0) { }
```

So It appears I am getting an empty statement and no errors are returned from SQL Server. Other SPs on the site use the same calls to DbAdaptor and work just fine.

Changing the query to

```
$res1 = sqlsrv_query($this->_db, $query, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC ) );
```

yields:

```
jjnj-dba-10
Query: exec getRisingStarFeatured 
jjnj-dba-20 dump follows: 
bool(false) 
jjnj-dba-30 post dump: 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 
[1] => 16954 [code] => 16954 
[2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Executing SQL directly; no cursor. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Executing SQL directly; no cursor. ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => 01S02 [SQLSTATE] => 01S02 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 
[2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Cursor type changed [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Cursor type changed ) ) 
jjnj-dba-40 post errors: 
bool(false)
```

Some additional information that may be helpful:

SQL Server 10.50.1600 - 875261 - DB\875261 - admin

Comment: What happens if you execute that procedure in SSMS?

Comment: Runs fine, all of the SPs have been running via mssql in PHP 5 for a long time now.

Comment: Then this is a php issue. I am not any help there as I can't even spell it correctly. ;)